# Refuse to load the script

Tags: node.js, express, pug, content-security-policy

when we use script link in pug templete then this type of error occure in console,
we also set csp header in meta tag as well as set.header to server script

**Refused to load the script 'https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.1.1/mapbox-gl.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.**

this is my pug code

```
block append head
    meta(http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' api.mapbox.com js.stripe.com 'unsafe-inline'")
    script(src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.1.1/mapbox-gl.js')
    link(href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.1.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet')
    script(src='https://js.stripe.com/terminal/v1/')
```

Comment: This question isn't possible to definitively answer with the level of detail you've provided. What does your server's `Content-Security-Policy` header look like? Why have you set it in the headers as well as in a meta tag?

Answer (score 0):

If you set your CSP in both meta tag and response header anything will have to pass both policies. Modify or remove your response header CSP.

Comment: Looks like you are right. But the topicstarter did not understand the answer about multiple CSP operate and where the CSP HTTP header did come from, because it did not check the Helmet middleware CSP settings at the server yet.